# Mapping all derived types of a generic type in one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have a question concerning EF Core 2.1

I have a base type, let's name it `Customer`, from which `CustomerOld` and `CustomerNew` are derived. These are automatically stored in one table, so far so good.

Now I have a generic type for mapping `Customer` to `Product` :

```
public class CustomerToProduct<T> where T : Customer 
{ 
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public T Customer { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The derived types of `CustomerToProduct` have no specific properties. I just want to use them such as the Customer I access through the property `CustomerToProduct.Customer` is of the derived type.

I defined the DbSets for the derived types in my `DbContext` as follows, which of course leads to separate tables:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<OldCustomerToProduct> OldCustomerToProducts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewCustomerToProduct> NewCustomerToProducts { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

How do I store all derived Types of `CustomerToProduct<T>` in the same table? How do I define the `DbSets<>`?

Comment: Do the OldCustomer and NewCustomer types come from the same table?

Comment: yes, they do ! This is done automatically by ef core

Answer (score 0):

Yours looks like a good candedate for the mapping pattern TPH (Type per Hierarchy).
You can read more [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) about the topic.

Comment: Thanks. I knew vaguely about tph, but your post clarified something: my real question should be: How to implement TPH when the parent type is a generic one?